# Displaying CSS block based on array results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I have 4 divs with id's set to case0, case1, case2, case3. I want to display the divs based on the values in my array. Right now I have this:

```
//new_split = [1,0,3,2];

for (var j = 0; j <= 3 ; ++j) {

    if (new_split[j] >= 1) {

        console.log("case"+j+"="+new_split[j]);
        $("#case"+[j]).css("display","block"); 

    }

}
```

All I'm trying to do is see if the value of the array is above 0 and if it is set the corresponding div to `display:block`. For some reason it works for all the divs except case0. It seems to ignore that divs presence entirely.

Comment: Uhm, you have a condition checking if the value is equal to or more than 1, so why would it work with 0 ?

Comment: Because the condition only checks if the value of the array is equal to or more then one. Not the value of the div.

Comment: Nope, you're using the value from the array to target the ID, and you're effectively excluding `#case0` with that condition.

Comment: In that case it's working perfectly -> http://jsfiddle.net/25mP2/

Comment: You're right I just made my own jsfiddle and it works [also](http://jsfiddle.net/LepBf/1/). But it still seems to be broken within my project. Weird.

Comment: Turns out it was all because I misplaced the id="case0" within the wrong div. Should of looked at the html closer before overthinking it :p. Appreciate all the help though.